# How to increment by 1 or 2 in a for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have created this code that works, but I need it to be more versatile. Have a look:

```
if (card_task_e[1] > card_task_e[2]): #Starting with 1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[1])
    counte+=1
if (card_task_e[1] > card_task_e[4]):
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[1])
if (card_task_e[1] > card_task_e[6]):
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[1])
if (card_task_e[1] > card_task_e[8]):
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[1])
if (card_task_e[1] > card_task_e[10]):
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[1])
if (card_task_e[1] > card_task_e[12]):
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[1])
if (card_task_e[3] > card_task_e[4]): #Going onto 3
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[3])
if (card_task_e[3] > card_task_e[6]):
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[3])
if (card_task_e[3] > card_task_e[8]):
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[3])
if (card_task_e[3] > card_task_e[10]):
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[3])
if (card_task_e[3] > card_task_e[12]):
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[3])
if (card_task_e[5] > card_task_e[6]): #Going onto 5
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[5])
if (card_task_e[5] > card_task_e[8]):
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[5])
if (card_task_e[5] > card_task_e[10]):
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[5])
if (card_task_e[5] > card_task_e[12]):
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[5])
if (card_task_e[7] > card_task_e[8]): #Going onto 7
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[7])
if (card_task_e[7] > card_task_e[10]):
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[7])
if (card_task_e[7] > card_task_e[12]):
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[7])
if (card_task_e[9] > card_task_e[10]): #Going onto 9
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[9])
if (card_task_e[9] > card_task_e[12]):
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[9])
if (card_task_e[11] > card_task_e[12]): #Finishing with 11
    counte+=1
    ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[11])
```

As you can see, I have a lot of if conditions, and I feel like it can be easily more efficient if I put a for loop, but I am really not sure how to do it in Python.

Just a note, the length of the array "card_task_e" can change from being as low as 0 or as being as high as 50.

If someone could help me out on how to make it better with for loops, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  That's a lot of code! Can you try and slim it down into a [mcve]?

Comment: [Python Tutorial `for` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Comment: Haha, it is supposed to check if the first value of the array is larger than the rest of the even indexes in the array.

Comment: `all([a[0] > i for i in a[1:2:]])` Note that arrays are zero based...

Comment: The first thing one can notice about this code is that it is repetitive. That is **always** wrong! If the code is repetitive, there is always a better way to do it. As @EugeneSh suggested, it can be done in one line, although a bit differently. To compare only with items at even indexes, do: `all([a[0] > item for item in a[2::2]])`

Comment: You wouldnt even need `all` - a `max(..)` over all the even elements would do as well and compare if the 0th is bigger then that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but some variation of this *will* work ;-)

```
n = len(card_task_e)
for i in range(1, n, 2):
    base = card_task_e[i]
    for j in range(i+1, n, 2):
        if base > card_task_e[j]:
            counte += 1
            ol_task_e.append(base)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want nested loops for this.

```
for a in range(1,12,2):
    for b in range(a+1,13,2):
        if card_task_e[a] > card_task_e[b]:
            ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[a])
            counte += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

> Haha, it is supposed to check if the first value of the array is larger than the rest of the even indexes in the array. – A. Bhatnagar

Why not simply test it using a list-slice?

```
a = [16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print ( a[0] > max ( a[2::2] ) ) # prints True

a = [16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,22]
print ( a[0] > max ( a[2::2] ) ) # prints False
```

`a[2::2]` starts with the 2nd element of `a` and takes every 2nd till its end. `max(..)` calculates the biggest one in it and `a[0] > max(..)` checks if the fist element of a is bigger then all other even values in that list.

Comment: I don't think the code does exactly what the OP thinks it does, and if it does, it doesn't do it very efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any length of `card_task_e`.

First, we loop through the odd integers, from 1 to the length. Inside that we loop between the even integers starting at the current odd index. The trailing 2 in each for loop tells the loop to increment by 2 in each iteration of the loop.

```
list_size = len(card_task_e)
for odd_index in range(1, list_size, 2):
    for even_index in range(odd_index + 1, list_size, 2):
        ol_task_e.append(card_task_e[odd_index])
        counte += 1
```

Answer (score -2):

You can reference a specific list element by using a counter that increments by 2 in each pass of the `for` loop.

```
counter = 0
for ____ in ____:
    counter += 2
    <do something to> some_list[counter]
```

You can also add `if` statements inside the loop to dictate how the counter is incremented.

Comment: That doesn't do what the question is asking how to do. Your shorthand is so short that you've failed to actually convey anything.

Comment: The question is "How to increment by 1 or 2 in a for loop"

Comment: The title of the question is "How to increment by 1 or 2 in a for loop". Then OP explained further what they actually wanted in the body of the question.

Comment: The body of the question doesn't make it clearer for me.  If this doesn't help, the OP can respond.